navigator.setDestination(waypoint) callback RouteStatus.LOCATION_DISABLED
Android sdk version :(com.google.android.libraries.navigation:navigation:6.0.0)
target device:An Android pad without a GPS hardware module, capable of WiFi positioning
when i use navigation demo,i set a destination,code interface
navigator.setDestination

return RouteStatus.LOCATION_DISABLED ,can not return RouteStatus.OK
but now
onGpsAvailabilityUpdate return true

withNavigatorAsync {
  Log.d(TAG,"waypoint = "+waypoint?.position)
  val pendingRoute = navigator.setDestination(waypoint)

  // Set an action to perform when a route is determined to the destination
  pendingRoute?.setOnResultListener { code ->
    when (code) {
      RouteStatus.OK -> {
        // Hide the toolbar to maximize the navigation UI
        actionBar?.hide()

        // Enable voice audio guidance (through the device speaker)
        navigator.setAudioGuidance(Navigator.AudioGuidance.VOICE_ALERTS_AND_GUIDANCE)

        // Simulate vehicle progress along the route (for demo/debug builds)
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
          navigator.simulator.simulateLocationsAlongExistingRoute(
            SimulationOptions().speedMultiplier(5f)
          )
        }

        // Start turn-by-turn guidance along the current route
        navigator.startGuidance()
      }
      RouteStatus.ROUTE_CANCELED -> showToast("Route guidance cancelled.")
      RouteStatus.NO_ROUTE_FOUND,
      RouteStatus.NETWORK_ERROR ->
        // TODO: Add logic to handle when a route could not be determined
        showToast("Error starting guidance: $code")
      else -> showToast("Error starting guidance: $code")
    }
  }
}

    NavigationApi.getRoadSnappedLocationProvider(application).addLocationListener(object :
      RoadSnappedLocationProvider.GpsAvailabilityEnhancedLocationListener {
      override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location?) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onLocationChanged location = $p0")
      }

      override fun onRawLocationUpdate(p0: Location?) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onRawLocationUpdate location = $p0")
      }

      override fun onGpsAvailabilityUpdate(p0: Boolean) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onGpsAvailabilityUpdate location = $p0")
      }

    })


onGpsAvailabilityUpdate callback true  

